# what do you mean by "draw chalk lines around the topic"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In a presentation's speaker note, I found a phrase;

> "Before we discuss the points (presented on the previous slide), let's draw some chalk lines around the topic and talk about challenges we see in this field".

what do you mean by "draw some chalk lines around the topic" here ?

Answer (score 3):

[To mark out a problem](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwjt9Z_69uHVAhWCA5oKHYBADo0QFgg3MAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FChalk_line&usg=AFQjCNEE799tOJnxP6s7ZXTTyjZh3EOo5w), to define it more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it refers to crime scenes where a chalk outline is drawn around the body (for later detailed investigation).

In your context, maybe it means giving a summary before going into the detailed information.